# Can default checks against null be done in a better way?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, null-check

Quite often I find myself in need of writing stuff similar to:

```
_parsedBetData["prizeLevel"] = params["prizeLevel"] == null ? "default" : params["prizeLevel"];
```

I am curious if there is a better way to do this? My main concern is that I have to write the *params["prizeLevel"]* twice.

Of course this could be extracted to a function similar to:

```
_parsedBetData["prizeLevel"] = defaultIfNull(params["prizeLevel"], "foo");

function defaultIfNull(o:*, default:*):* {
    return o == null ? default : o;
}
```

But then I would have to have access to this function from wherever I want to do this checkup. Thus I'm wondering if there's some smart way of solving this issue. Maybe with the help of some kind of bit-magic? Or is prototyping/dynamic something appliable here?

The best solution I have come up with this far is to make a macro inside the code IDE that makes some specific keyboard combination write this. But I bet someone has a better idea.

Comment: I'm not saying this is true in your case, but usually having to repeatedly test for null on the same object can mean you need to rethink your design. Maybe you need to set some kind of default to the object so you can still handle it and it will never be null, even if that object does nothing.

Comment: @Neil: Yes, good point, good to have here for reference. But in this case this is that "default" situation. I'm assigning values to the "view-model" unless they are provided as launch parameters/in the server response etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perhaps the syntax you're looking for:

```
_parsedBetData["prizeLevel"] = params["prizeLevel"] || "default";
```

To set _parsedBetData["prizeLevel"] to default if it is null, you can do

```
_parsedBetData["prizeLevel"] ||= "default";
```

This might not do exactly what you want, since an empty string evaluates to false also.

Comment: Thank you, this is the stuff that I'm looking for :)) Good to know that empty strings evaluates to false

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the [logical OR assignment](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#logical_OR_assignment) is what you're looking for :)

You could do

> params["prizeLevel"] ||= "default";

If you want it to be in some other variable, then use a simple [OR operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#logical_OR)

> _parsedBetData["prizeLevel"] = params["prizeLevel"] || "default";

**--EDIT--**

Both 32bitkid and cleong are right. You should use logical operators, not the bitwise ones.

Comment: I think you mean `||` (logical or) not `|` (bitwise or)